# How to devise this solution to Non-Constructible Change challenge from Algoexpert.io

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm working through algoexpert.io coding challenges and I'm having trouble undersatnding the suggested solution to one of the questions titled **Non-Constructible Change**

Here's the challenge question:

Given an array of positive integers representing the values of coins in your
possession, write a function that returns the minimum amount of change (the
minimum sum of money) that you **cannot** create. The given coins can have
any positive integer value and aren't necessarily unique (i.e., you can have
multiple coins of the same value).

For example, if you're given coins = [1, 2, 5], the minimum
amount of change that you can't create is 4. If you're given no
coins, the minimum amount of change that you can't create is 1.

```
// O(nlogn) time, O(n) size.
function nonConstructibleChange(coins) {
  coins = coins.sort((a, b) => a - b); // O(nlogn) time operation
  let change = 0;

  for (coin of coins) {
    if (coin > change + 1) return change + 1;
    change += coin;
  }

  return change + 1;
}
```

My problem

I am not completely sure how did the author of the solution come up with the intuition that

```
if the current coin is greater than `change + 1`, the smallest impossible change is equal to `change + 1`.
```

I can see how it tracks, and indeed the algorithm passes all tests, but I'd like to know more about a process I could use to devise this rule.

Thank you for taking the time to read the question!

Comment: I'm afraid there's no formula for creativity.

Comment: ... and I don't mean that previous comment to be snide.  This is an elegant answer to the problem, and I'm not sure I would have seen it.  I'd suggest trying to figure out how *you* would solve this and then iterate upon it to see if you can improve it.  Sometimes an "aha* moment will sneak up on you.  And other times you simply toil away until you get something that works without elegant insights.  Both can get the job done, although the leaps of intuition are more satisfying.

Answer (score 27):

This one took me a while too, but this was how I made sense of it:

Assume you've proven you can make 1-8 cents.

You go to the next iteration and want to know if you can make 9 cents. So you iterate to the next new coin in the sorted list.

if newCoin < 9:

- You know for a fact that you can make 9 cents.
- Example if the new coin is 5: Use that new coin and subtract it from the total you're trying to make. 9 - 5 = 4. Then however way you made 4 previously just do that again. (You've already proven you can make 1-8 cents)

if newCoin == 9:

- You know for a fact that you can make 9 cents.
- Just use the 9 cent coin

if newCoin > 9:

- You know for a fact that you CANNOT make 9 cents
- This is because **you can't use the new coin**. For example, a 10 cent coin is useless to you when you're trying to make 9 cents since it's too big (can't make 9)
- **You're also screwed if you don't use the new coin** because if you add up all the coins you've seen so far, you've only been able to make 8 (can't make 9)

And that's where the change + 1 comes from. (your variable change = 8)

```
if the current coin is greater than `change + 1`, the smallest impossible change is equal to `change + 1`.
```

Comment: This is helpful. It's also important a) that the coins are sorted first, so that you know that any remaining coins are the same as or bigger than the next one. And it's _also_ important b) to consider the issue of gaps. If you have a set of _constructible_ values with gaps in, and you add a new coin (allowed by the `<= max+1` rule), then you get a new set of values, also with gaps. So (imho, after trying to get my head round it too!) it's important to see that the algorithm also ensures that there will never be gaps in the list of values, at any step. C.f. @HemantJoshi's also useful answer.

Comment: @MikeBeaton rightly said! Because of the sorting, the algorithm returns once the first gap is found. Been thinking why the guys at algoexpert did not mention this point clearly.

Answer (score 6):

When integers are sorted, we can always track the highest constructible value by doing a cumulative sum of the sorted integers.

For example, `coins = [1, 2, 5] ==> 1,2,3,5,6,7`

At any point, if the next integer is larger than max constructible + 1, then there is no way to construct max constructible + 1.

```
[1]       mc=1     ---> 2
[1, 2]    mc=3     ---> 4
[1, 2, 5] mc=7     ---> 8
```

If the current integer is greater than `mc + 1`, the smallest impossible change is equal to `mc + 1`.

So in this case, for `[1, 2, 5]` the smallest value is 4.

It can be done like this (i am using go)

```
    func NonConstructibleChange(array []int) int {
        sort.Ints(array)
        ncc :=1
        for i:=0; i< len(array) && array[i]<=ncc; i++{
            ncc +=array[i]
        }
        return ncc
    }
```

Comment: "When integers are sorted, we can always track the highest constructible value by doing a cumulative sum of the sorted integers."

How do you know for sure that knowing this cumulative sum of sorted integers means that we can construct the value for all values between 1 and the cumulative sum? None of the solutions I've seen explain how we came to that conclusion, they kinda just give it as something that is evident.

Comment: If you re-read a couple of times (I had to!) @HemantJoshi is not saying you can construct every value up to the highest constructible value. He is _just_ saying that it is the highest value you can construct. There may be gaps - and in the first example, there _is_ a gap, at 4. So looking for the highest _non-_ constructible value is basically looking for the first gap! :-)

Answer (score 3):

After a while thinking about that, I thought it was a probability problem. I mean, how many changes are possible given N coins?

This mean that I should combine every possibility. For example, given `coins = [1, 5, 9]`, what's the minimum amount of change that can be made?

```
1 -> 1, 1+5, 1+9, 1+5+9.  
5 -> 5, 5+9.  
9 -> 9.
```

resulting in `possible changes = [1, 6, 10, 15, 14, 9]`.
Then, the minimum amount of change that can be created using this 3 coins `[1, 5, 9]` should be `2`.

By the way, if that was the case, this is a `O(2^n) time` because for every new coin (every new possibility) the number of calculations double.

---

Unfortunately, that is not the case...

Comment: 2 _is_ indeed the minimal amount of change that _cannot_ be created with these three coins - so it is indeed the correct answer! And this is a correct (but inefficient) way of solving the problem. (A _problem_ is O(n) if an O(n) algorithm is the fastest solution - this does not mean that there cannot be a different, _correct_, but less efficient, e.g. O(n^2) solution, as here.)

Answer (score 1):

From the AlgoExpert comments @jfebrian:

---

I also don't get it at first, but now I get it. This is how I got it.

Lets say our minimum_change is 7, it basically means that with our current coins we can make from 1,2,3,...,7.

Now, we already have a fact, that we can make any coin from 1 to 7, right?
Then, whatever coin (n) we add to it, we will be able to make n+1, n+2, n+3, ... n+7.

Now, the reason why n must be less than minimum_change + 1 for us to add it to our minimum change is that:

If n is greater than minimum_change+1, then we can't make minimum_change+1 with our coins.

For example, our new coin is 9. We can make 9+1, 9+2, ..., 9+7, but we can't make 8.
To make 8 we need any coin less than or equal to 8.

If we have 8 we can just use that coin. If we have 7 we can add 1 to it. If we have 6 we can add 2 to it, and so on.

---

Answer (score 0):

I managed to tackle it without the + 1 thing, by tracking the current minimum impossible change, like so:

```
function nonConstructibleChange(coins) {
  let currentMinImpossibleChange = 1;
    
  const sortedCoins = coins.sort((a,b) => a-b)
    
  for(let i = 0; i < sortedCoins.length ; i += 1) {
    if(currentMinImpossibleChange < sortedCoins[i]) return currentMinImpossibleChange
    currentMinImpossibleChange += sortedCoins[i];
  }
    
  return currentMinImpossibleChange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the key was:

Having coins [1,2] we know we can create 1, 2, 3. So, what if we add a new coin:

a) adding 4 -> [1,2,4], we could be able to create 4, 4+1, 4+2, 4+3

b) adding 5 -> [1,2,5], we could be able to create 5, 5+1, 5+2, 5+3, but could not be able to create 4

So that's why you can not create amountOfChange + 1 if the new coin > amountOfChange + 1
In other words, you can not create 4 if the new coin is 5 or bigger

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to understand the solution when I tried to solve it for the case when a fractional coin value is possible. For example, if the coin may have a value of 0.5 and 2.5 (I've seen such old coins personally).

In this case we need to compare the subsequent coin with the min change we have so far + the value of the possible smallest coin value.

let say we have the change for up to 1.5, but the next coin is 2.5:

2.5 > 1.5 + 0.5 (instead of 1, 0.5 is the smallest possible coin now) then we are resulting 1.5 + 0.5 = 2 is the smallest non-constructible change

just think about `change + 1` as `change + smallestPossibleCoinValue`, where smallestCoinValue is the smallest possible coin value, constrained to "1" just for this particular task (the coins array is an array of integers).

Answer (score 0):

To make sense of this problem, let's use a metaphor and a visualization. Imagine the coins are not coins, but instead, they represent different jump sizes. Each coin represents a potential jump distance based on the size of the array element. For instance, when we have the array [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 22], we could potentially jump 1 unit forward, or 2 units, or 3, and so on.

The objective is to cover all points on the x-axis. The first point that we cannot reach by jumping according to the array elements is the point of interest in this problem.

Please refer to the drawing below for a clearer explanation:

[image: Minimum non-constructible change]