# How to write brute-force for smallest change algorithm?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For this algorithm challenge:

write a function that returns the min amount of change that you cannot create.

```
function nonConstructibleChange(coins) {


coins = coins.sort((a, b) => a - b); // O(nlogn) time operation
  console.log(coins)
  let change = 0;

  for (coin of coins) {
    if (coin > change + 1) return change + 1;
    change += coin;
  }

  return change + 1;
}
console.log(nonConstructibleChange([5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 22]));
```

returns 20

I couldnt find a brute-force solution for it, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: sorry added the context

Comment: Why do you want a brute force technique? To avoid using sort?

Comment: to understand it on a more basic level.

Answer (score -1):

You could construct every single possible combination of one or more coins, sum each combination to get its total value, then (from here following the solution you've posted) you could sort those totals, then search, starting from zero, for the first jump by more than one in the total?

Or to make it even more inefficient, don't even sort the totals, but just go through every total multiple times, searching first for 1, then for 2, then 3... and stop and report the first value you don't find.

Comment: is it okay if you can give me some example in code?

Comment: Btw @ScottSauyet's second comment to https://stackoverflow.com/q/67099988 more or less explains why you need to work out the code (if not preferably the algorithm as well!) for _yourself_, if you do want to understand the problem and solution better.